# Infopath, submitting a section at a time and then locking that section

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I have an InfoPath form which has three sections. I want to submit one section at a time to a SharePoint list and when that section has submitted the user can't go back to change what's been entered on the form. Any suggestions? I'm pretty new to InfoPath but I'm thinking locking the sections would be done via rules?

Comment: Yes, you can set rules in the button click. FYI, you can also use code-behind (C#) to hide section if you wanted also.

Comment: Ideally I don't want to use any code. So I'd create a submit button and add a rule to that to lock that section after submitting?

Comment: Or hide it if you want.

Comment: http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/9736.aspx explains how to do this very easily. Hope it helps.